# Gitleaks not scanning private repo properly

Tags: github, access-token, gitleaks

So I am trying to run gitleaks on my organizations private GitHub page. This is the command I am using for reference:

```
gitleaks --baseurl=company_url/api/v3/ --org="XXXX" --threads=10 --report="report.csv" --config="gitleaks.toml" --host=Github --access-token="access_token"
```

The problem is that the output is showing it didn't even scan anything:

```
INFO[2021-01-20T14:25:28-05:00] no leaks found, skipping writing report      
INFO[2021-01-20T14:25:28-05:00] No leaks detected. 0 commits audited in 0 seconds
```

It obviously is not able to access the company's url page for whatever reason. I can also verify that the access token, url, organization code are all correct as I use them for other scripts without issue.

I'm running gitleaks 4.1.0 for reference. Any help on this would be appreciated.